# NestJs redirect without response usage

Tags: javascript, node.js, nestjs

Is it possible to make a redirect from a `Nest` controller without the usage of the `@Response` object?

For now I know that we can only do this via direct `@Response` object injection into the route handler.

Comment: Can you add your code of how you're handling the redirect with the Response object?

Comment: @KimKern, it's the usual one. res.redirect(someVal). Nothing special.

Comment: May I ask you what is problematic using `@Res`? If you're just asking out of curiosity, then I can tell you I never saw it done an other way than using `res.redirect`

Comment: @VinceOPS, Mostly it's disabling default handling for nest. But, good catch here, it is not breaking anything mission critical. I can proceed with ```res.redirect```.

Comment: It would be very useful when testing controllers. mocking whole response objects is quite tiresome...

Answer (score 4):

You can write a `RedirectInterceptor`:

```
@Injectable()
export class RedirectInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, stream$: Observable<any>): Observable<any> {
    const response = context.switchToHttp().getResponse();
    response.redirect('redirect-target');
    return stream$;
  }
}
```

Then use it in your controller like this:

```
@Get('user')
@UseInterceptors(RedirectInterceptor)
getUser() {
  // will be redirected.
}
```

**It is important not to return anything from your controller**, otherwise you will get the following error: `Can't set headers after they are sent.`

If needed the `RedirectInterceptor` can be dynamic as well:

```
@Injectable()
export class RedirectInterceptor implements NestInterceptor {
  constructor(private readonly target: string) {}
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

  intercept(context: ExecutionContext, stream$: Observable<any>): Observable<any> {
    const response = context.switchToHttp().getResponse();
    response.redirect(this.target);
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^
    return stream$;
  }
}
```

and then in the controller:

```
@UseInterceptors(new RedirectInterceptor('redirect-target'))
```

Answer (score 2):

(a bit of a different implementation to another answer here...)

I created a `RedirectError` which can be thrown more dynamically than a decorator

```
import { ExceptionFilter, Catch, ArgumentsHost } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Response } from 'express';

export class RedirectError extends Error {
  constructor(public readonly status: number, public readonly url: string) {
    super();
  }
}

@Catch(RedirectError)
export class RedirectFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  public catch(exception: RedirectError, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    const ctx = host.switchToHttp();
    const response = ctx.getResponse<Response>();
    return response.redirect(exception.status, exception.url);
  }
}
```

and then in `main.ts` set it:

```
  app.useGlobalFilters(new RedirectFilter());
```

and finally to use it:

```
throw new RedirectError(302, '/some-target');
```

Answer (score 1):

I've done it more complex, but I think it is good enough.

1. Create a class such as util/RedirectException like this:

The code like this:

```
import { HttpException, HttpStatus } from '@nestjs/common';

export class RedirectException extends HttpException {
  constructor(message?: string | object) {
    super(message, HttpStatus.CONTINUE);
  }
}
```

2. Create a `RedirectFilter` by: `nest g f RedirectFilter`

Write the code like this:

```
import { ArgumentsHost, Catch, ExceptionFilter, HttpException, HttpStatus } from '@nestjs/common';
import { RedirectException } from './util/redirect-exception';

@Catch()
export class RedirectFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
 catch(exception: any, host: ArgumentsHost) {
  const res = host.switchToHttp().getResponse(),
  req = host.switchToHttp().getRequest();
  try {
    if (exception instanceof RedirectException) {
      Object.keys(exception.message).forEach(k => {
        req.session[k] = exception.message[k];
      });
      req.session.save(() => {
        res.redirect(exception.message.url);
      });
      return;
    }

    if (exception instanceof HttpException) {
      return res.status(exception.status).json(exception.message)
    }
    res.status(500).json({status: 500, message: 'Internal Server error'})
   } catch (e) {
    return res.status(500)
      .json({
        status: HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR,
        message: e.message
      });
   }
  }
}
```

This class help you handle all the response when an exception is throw. And yes, this include the Redirect exception. Now we can throw the exception with exactly params, and it work!

3. Use the filter in `main.ts`: `app.useGlobalFilters(new RedirectFilter());`
4. And in controller, if you want to redirect to an url, just do this any time you want

Code:

```
 throw new RedirectException({
    url: 'the url you want to redirect',
    field1: 'The first field you want to pass to session'
    field2: 'The second field you want to pass to session'
 });
```

5. Don't forget setup express-session if you want to pass data by session when redirect: https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session.

If you don't want to use this, just replace the code inside `if (exception instanceof RedirectException) {}` to: `res.redirect(exception.message.url);`. It don't check and setup the session anymore.

Comment: Actually, this is not the best way, as you are using exceptions here for flow control, which should be done in normal code execution way. There are plenty of resources that describes why it is bad do flow control tasks through exceptions throw.

Comment: I know it's not the best way. But it's the only way that I can think to.

The problem is: What can I do when I want to redirect to another URL in an "if" statement. And then make the method "return"?

If you return, things will be like #2 comment.

Forget about "if else" or "else" statement. I'm not used them for years. And sometimes, my mate will write `return res.redirect('/')`, and then make the server crash, and then,... I make the code to avoid them do that. Avoid as much as things will make the nodejs server crash!